# Pyrocms Field type usage

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

How to create text input field in pyrocms ? I read this API http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/field-types, but didn't understand how to create input field in my theme layout

I tried like this in my layout, output is nothing

This is my understanding, to use field_type

```
 {{ field_type] : [function_name] [argument varisbales] }}
```

I tried like this on layout

```
 {{ text:form_output name="test" }}
```

May be my understanding is wrong.

If anyone used this module, kindly share I have no past experience with Pyrocms

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is the text input field for? If we can understand your objective then we can propose a solution. For example, the text field is probably for use in a form. What is the form's purpose ? Maybe Streams has the solution for you. See [the Streams documentation here.](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/streams/entry-form)

Comment: Stream is Default,  I have created new field, along with default `body` with name and slug is `captcha` where field type is `CAPTCHA`, I am trying add captcha to default core module contact. I can see captcha images in admin view here `admin -> pages -> edit_page -> page_content`, so its confirmed that `field_type` loaded successfully, but how to show and validate this captcha inside `layout.html` in my theme. I don't know the syntax